# MongoDb how to subtract 2 years and use the result to find that year(result) in Mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I am new at MongoDB, I have a database that contains information about Private and public companies. information such as founding year, number of employees, deadpoolyear, etc.  (sample attached as picture)

I need to filter only companies that have been Deadpool after the third year, it means that they have been Deadpool 3 years after the founding year.

i do have the Founding year, but the deadpool year shows which year it was deadpooled. I think the solution is to add 3 years to the founding year and filter everything to that new year in all the database, so i can get only companies that were deadpool the third year.

i will really appreciate the help.

```
founded_year:2004
founded_month:8
founded_day:1
deadpooled_year:2008
deadpooled_month:3
deadpooled_day:3
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g76Ez.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options. If you are using Mongo >=3.6 you can make use of the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator which allows you to use the more complex aggregation operators and perform the comparison:

```
const query = {
  $expr: {
    $eq: [{
       $subtract: ['$deadpooled_year', '$founded_year']
      },
      3
    ]
  }
}
// Then perform your query as normal 
db.companies.find(query).then(...
```

If 3.6 is not available you can use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/index.html) which is less performant and pass it an expression/function that will do the comparison such as:

```
{ $where: function() { return this.deadpooled_year - this.founded_year === 3 } }
```

Alternatively you can use the `$eq`, `$subtract` operators using the aggregation framework but it may not be necessary in your case.

Comment: Hello CyberWombat, ok but how do i do this inside mongo? my mongo version is 3.6.5, i tried with $expr  with the conditional 3 as in your example but then im not sure what to do after that, how do i use that to then find the companies that got deadpool after 3 years? 

db.companies.find({$founded_year: {$eq: query}}) . ??

thank you again for your kind help

Comment: Perhaps I am not clear on your need. The way I understood your question was: "Find all items which have a deadpool year value that is exactly 3 years beyond that of the founding year". Is that not what you are asking? If not perhaps post a few sample database entries and explain which should be returned.

Comment: Ive updated my answer to use your variable names in case it wasn't clear.

Comment: that was very helpful it works, i appreciate very much, thanks